# node.JS - can't get redis to work

Tags: node.js, redis

I have installed redis using "npm install redis". Then I run the sample code prodvided by this project page [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis). I got this

```
 "error error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - EPERM, Operation not permitted"
```

I think I'm missing something here, can someone help me point it out? Below is the code I used

```
var redis = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient();

client.on("error", function (err){
    console.log("Error " + err);
});

client.set("string key", "string val", redis.print);
client.hset("hash key", "hashtest 1", "some value", redis.print);
client.hset(["hash key", "hashtest 2", "some other value"], redis.print);
client.hkeys("hash key", function (err, replies) {
    console.log(replies.length + " replies:");
    replies.forEach(function (reply, i) {
        console.log("    " + i + ": " + reply);
    });
    client.quit();
});
```

Comment: Is `127.0.0.6379` a typo in the question or is that exactly as it appears in the error message? Should be `127.0.0.1:6379` to connect to redis on localhost.

Comment: Just to confirm: you've launched a Redis instance on localhost on port 6379 (the default port) before running your code, right? If so, do you have a local firewall running?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by "you've launched a Redis instance"? I just run the code and I got error. And I don't have a firewall.

Comment: @runrunforest - you need to run the redis server first. node_redis is just a client. click [here](http://redis.io/download) for a link to download and instructions on how to setup the redis server. Once the server is up and running, try running your node script then.

Comment: @runrunforest: can you run redis-cli command from your terminal?

Comment: I was trying to compile redis but the compilation failed. Please refer the sreen shot to see errors vietnamlist.net/pic/5849813813039661181385560_full.png

Answer (score 12, accepted):

node_redis is a package which lets you access Redis from NodeJS, much like MySQL-Python is a package which lets you access MySQL from Python. In both cases you need to have an actual instance of the database (e.g. Redis or MySQL) running for your code to connect to.

You should install Redis (depending on your OS there will be different ways to do this, but on OSX you could run `port install redis` or on Ubuntu you could run `apt-get install redis-server` or check out the instructions here http://redis.io/download) and then run it with the `redis-server` command, which would start up an instance on the default port (6379).

It also looks like there are some Windows builds here: http://code.google.com/p/servicestack/wiki/RedisWindowsDownload

Comment: I was trying to compile redis but the compilation failed. Please refer the sreen shot to see errors http://www.vietnamlist.net/pic/5849813813039661181385560_full.png

Comment: what version of what compiler are you using?

Comment: If you're on windows you could also consider getting a Windows build of Redis instead of compiling it yourself if you're having issues: http://code.google.com/p/servicestack/wiki/RedisWindowsDownload

Answer (score 5):

For Windows users,

download the redis-server from here.
https://github.com/dmajkic/redis/downloads

this worked for me, but I am still searching on
a way to host a redis database.

Answer (score 0):

I am on mac and had to open two tabs in my terminal:

- One for `redis-server`
- Other for `nodemon myServer.js`

Hope it helps